# Query with condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a query with a condition and pagination, I think I am writing in a wrong way the code because the next code return the whole records, hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

MODEL

```
function getProductosById($table,$fields,$where,$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){


        $this->db->select('categorias.*, produtos.*');
        $this->db->from('categorias');
        $this->db->join('produtos','categorias.idCategoria = produtos.categoriaid');
        $where = "categorias.idCategoria = produtos.categoriaid";

        if($where){
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
        $this->db->order_by('idProdutos','desc');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
        return $result;


    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function visualizar(){

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCategoria')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No tiene permiso para visualizar categorias.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }


        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $categoriaid = $this->uri->segment(3);  

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/categorias/visualizar/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->categorias_model->countProd('produtos', $categoriaid);
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['next_link'] = 'Próxima';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination alternate"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a style="color: #2D335B"><b>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'Primera';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Última';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

        $this->data['productos'] = $this->categorias_model->getProductosById('produtos','idProdutos, descricao, estoque','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->data['view'] = 'categorias/visualizarCategoria';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);


    }
```

Comment: Without digging too deep, I think you want to delete the line `$where = "..."` as that would override any where condition passed into the function. It seems to be a repeat of the join condition, and won't accomplish anything.

Comment: thanks for answaer Jerry! I did it but the result is the same.

Comment: What is the result and what do you want it to be?

Comment: One other thing I see is that you are ignoring your `$fields` parameter in the query. You probably want your `select` to be limited to those fields.

Comment: return the whole records.

Comment: $fields is here 
`$this->data['productos'] = $this->categorias_model->getProductosById('produtos','idProdutos, descricao, estoque','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));`